# How to retrieve the screen resolution of all users?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, xorg, citrix, desktop-recording

I am trying to implement a **session recording** system which could work as CCTV targetting users' screen. I need this system to monitor users' operations.

After preliminary studies, ffmpeg was brought up.

> ffmpeg -video_size **SCREEN_SIZE** -framerate 30 -f x11grab -i **DISPLAY** -c:v libx264 -crf 18 /tmp/recording.mp4

In the above command, **DISPLAY** could be retrieved by searching through **/proc/*PID_OF_GNOME_SESSION*/environ**, while I have not figured out a solution to get the **SCREEN_SIZE** of each user.

Please help me to get this value of all users. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you expect to have different users using different resolutions? That would be quite atypical.

Comment: @ChanganAuto This is truly atypical, so I ask this question here. As the users connect to the Ubuntu server via Citrix (a way of remote desktop), probably the monitor resolution of each user is different, so will be the screen resolution of each Citrix session (gnome session).